# Unity Catalog - Access External location with a Service Principal

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

I am trying to access Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 with a Service Principal via Unity Catalog.

- Managed Identity is added with Contributor Role assigned to the storage account
- Managed Identity is added as a Storage Credential
- the storage container is added as an external location with this credential
- the Service Principal is added with `All Privileges` on the external location

In PySpark I set the Spark config according to the Azure Gen 2 documentation:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

spark.conf.set(f"fs.azure.account.auth.type.{storage_account}.dfs.core.windows.net", "OAuth")
spark.conf.set(f"fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type.{storage_account}.dfs.core.windows.net", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider")
spark.conf.set(f"fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id.{storage_account}.dfs.core.windows.net", client_id)
spark.conf.set(f"fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret.{storage_account}.dfs.core.windows.net", client_secret)
spark.conf.set(f"fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint.{storage_account}.dfs.core.windows.net", f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/token")

# create and write dataframe
df = spark.createDataFrame(["10","11","13"], StringType()).toDF("values")
df.write \
  .format("delta") \
  .mode("overwrite") \
  .save(f"abfss://{container}@{storage_account}.dfs.core.windows.net/example/example-0")
```

This unfortunaly this returns an unexpected:

> Operation failed: "This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.", 403, HEAD, https://{storage-account}.dfs.core.windows.net/{container-name}/example/example-0?upn=false&action=getStatus&timeout=90

Comment: 'trying to access Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 with a Service Principal via Unity Catalog' you mentioned that you have used unity catalogue. can you add where you are using Unity catalogue in the above code?

Comment: Well I only added the permissions and expect databricks to do some magic to give access to the container. When I run the `df.write` with a personal cluster where I add my personal ID to the external location it works. I am missing the documentation where I "add" Unity Catalog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use Unity Catalog you don't need these properties - they were needed prior to Unity Catalog and not used right now, or used only for clusters without UC for direct data access:

```
spark.conf.set(f"fs.azure.account.auth.type.{storage_account}.dfs.core.windows.net", "OAuth")
spark.conf.set(f"fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type.{storage_account}.dfs.core.windows.net", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider")
spark.conf.set(f"fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id.{storage_account}.dfs.core.windows.net", client_id)
spark.conf.set(f"fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret.{storage_account}.dfs.core.windows.net", client_secret)
spark.conf.set(f"fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint.{storage_account}.dfs.core.windows.net", f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/token")
```

The authentication to the given storage location will happen via mapping the storage credential to the external location path.

But permissions will be checked for the user/service principal who is running a giving piece of code, so this user/principal should have corresponding permission on the external location. If you run this code as SP-assigned job, then it will have access. But if you run it as yourself, it won't work until you get permissions.

Comment: This is absolutely clear -- I was running from some custom cluster and found later [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-governance/unity-catalog/compute#--what-is-cluster-access-mode) that this is not supported by UC

Answer (score 1):

> Operation failed: "This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.", 403, HEAD,https://{storage account}.dfs.core.windows.net/{container-name}/example/example-0?upn=false.

The above error mainly happens because no proper access to service principle  with Storage account.

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment I got the same error**.

[image]

**To resolve the above error. Please follow this approach:**

First go to your Azure Storage Account -> Containers -> Manage ACL

[image]

Inside Manage ACL Add Service principle and Access permissions as shown in the image.

[image]

Now, you can check the Azure Databricks connected to Azure Data Lake Gen2.

```
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.auth.type.<Storage_account>.dfs.core.windows.net", "OAuth")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type.<storage_account>.dfs.core.windows.net", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id.<storage_account>.dfs.core.windows.net", "<client_id>")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret.<storage_account>.dfs.core.windows.net", "<client_secret>")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint.vamblob.dfs.core.windows.net", "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/token")

   
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
df = spark.createDataFrame(["10","11","13"], StringType()).toDF("values")

display(df)
```

[image]

Write Dataframe from Azure Databricks to Gen2

```
df.write \
.format("delta") \
.mode("overwrite") \
.save(f"abfss://<container>@<<storage_account>.dfs.core.windows.net/example/example-0")
```

[image]